# How can I change the browser user agent with javascript/html?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, user-agent

I have an app running in IE7. However, one of the analytics app I use just updated and requires minimum IE8. Is there a javascript/html way to spoof the User Agent in IE7 to be detected as IE8?

This is what I am doing so far but it is not working in IE7

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function() {
    return 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; InfoPath.2; SV1; .NET CLR 3.3.69573; WOW64; en-US)';
    });
    alert(navigator.userAgent);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to change the User Agent of IE7 to IE8 through javascript/html only. I don't have access to the windows registry.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have access to the browser environment from JavaScript .. that would be an abuse vector, no?

Comment: You can just use some extension for browser, like Default User Agent. Or check this out: http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/

Comment: @AleksandarPopovic I can do it manually yes. However I wanted to know if there was a javascript/html way. Its for a client who will be using this app on multiple machines running IE7.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot change the UA String of the browser from script. You can do it with an extension or the registry.

But the premise of your question is wrong-- if you change the UA string to "trick" the application, you may avoid the "You need to upgrade your browser" error message and instead you'll just have broken pages that are throwing exceptions or laying out incorrectly because they depend on IE8+ features that aren't present in IE7.

IE7 is crusty, insecure, and shouldn't be used any longer.

Comment: +1 because you're right that the whole concept of the question is just wrong. But there *are* cases where sites use UA strings to block browsers that don't need to be blocked. It's a terrible practice, but if the OP has hit one of those sites, I can see why he might want to do this. But ultimately you're right, the solution is to do a browser upgrade, not try to kludge IE7 into working.